# swagger open api generator and enums with custom names

Tags: swagger, openapi-generator

i'am using swagger to generate an enum in java in open generator tool , and I have the following swagger :

```
      enum:
    - A : "activated"
    - D : "deactivated"
    - R : "registered"
    - S : "suspended"
```

the code generated is :

```
public enum Status {
```

A_ACTIVATED_("{"A":"activated"}"),

D_DEACTIVATED_("{"D":"deactivated"}"),

R_REGISTERED_("{"R":"registered"}"),

S_SUSPENDED_("{"S":"suspended"}");

private String value;
}

and I want to generate code like :

```
    public enum Status {
```

A("activated"),

D("deactivated"),

R("registered"),

S("suspended");

private String value;
}

thanks guys

Comment: enum is only an array with string values, not a key:value pair.

Comment: enums can have fields too